# AppleScript cannot click input tag to add file

Tags: javascript, html, applescript

I am trying to use applescript to add a file to a website's input field.

This is my code so far:

```
set ClickInput to "var myInput = document.getElementByClassName('jsx-1828163283 upload-btn-input')[0]; myInput.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown')); myInput.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseup'));"

set ClickInput2 to "var myInput = document.getElementsByName('upload-btn')[0]; myInput.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown')); myInput.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseup'));"

activate application "Safari"

tell application "Safari" 
   open location "https://www.example.com/upload"
   set theTab to tab 1 of window 1
    
   -- wait until page loads
   repeat while document 1's source = ""
      delay 0.5
   end repeat

   -- do JavaScript ClickInput in theTab
   do JavaScript ClickInput2 in theTab

   delay(5)

   close theTab

end tell
```

Here is the HTML around the input element I want to select:

```
<div class="jsx-3758851661 upload">
   <div class="jsx-1828163283 upload-btn">
      <div class="jsx-3758851661 card stage-1">
         <div class="jsx-3758851661 text-main">Select video to upload</div>
         <div class="jsx-3758851661 text-sub text-sub-margin">Or drag and drop a file</div>
         <br class="jsx-3758851661">
         <ul class="jsx-3758851661 text-sub">
            <li class="jsx-3758851661">MP4 or WebM</li>
            <li class="jsx-3758851661">720x1280 resolution or higher</li>
            <li class="jsx-3758851661">Up to 60 seconds</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <input type="file" name="upload-btn" accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*" class="jsx-1828163283 upload-btn-input">
   </div>
</div>
```

The way the site works is you click the outermost div `<div class="jsx-3758851661 upload">` and the safari file finder pops up and you select what file you want.

I have tried clicking the divs outside of the input tag and I have tried clicking the input tag by itself.

I tried to do this by selecting the classnames of the divs and the input tag

I also tried to do this by selecting the input tag by its name and clicking on that

None of these worked.

Im not sure if it clicked but none of these made the file finder pop up

Do you guys have any ideas? Let me know if you would like some clarification. thanks!

Comment: What is the actual **URL** of _web page_?

Comment: I just figured it out using `set ClickInput to "document.getElementsByName('upload-btn')[0].click();"` Thanks though! @user3439894

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured out `set ClickInput to "document.getElementsByName('upload-btn')[0].click();"` works !

Answer (score 0):

<s>`getElementsByName` isn’t a function that I’m aware exists as standard, so you probably want to use `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelector`.</s>

The `input` element has two class names, of which I’m going to choose `”upload-btn-input”` in my example below:

```
tell application id "com.apple.safari" 
        open location "https://www.example.com/upload"
        tell document 1
                repeat while the source = ""
                        delay 0.5
                end repeat
                do javascript "document.querySelector('.upload-btn-input').click();"
        end tell
end tell
```

If you can provide the actual URL of the page in question, this would allow me to refine this answer to ensure it’s appropriate for what you’re trying to do.

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked. The website is https://www.tiktok.com/upload/?lang=en

Comment: See, `getElementsByName` at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp

Comment: I have a question however, what is the downside of getElementsByName not being a standard?

Comment: @ZackBeucler I was wrong about that function.  I just wasn’t aware of it previously.  There’s nothing wrong with it.